# How do I pull a reference from a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Forgive me as my C++ is very rusty. But I am in a bind. I am trying to make a custom list that have methods to return the front most, and back most items.

```
ElementType& front() throw(string*)
{
   if (empty())
      throw new string("Empty Vector");
   else
      return(first)
}
```

My main problem is that I don't have the actual first item, I have a pointer to it and I have no idea how to go about taking a reference of what the pointer is pointing it, using only the pointer. I've tried things similar to:

```
ElementType& *first
```

or

```
&*first
```

but I can't get them to play nicely. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't throw naked pointers. It raises ownership questions.

Comment: Why are you throwing strings? Why are throwing by pointer rather then reference? Why do you have parens around your return expression.

Comment: And in that spirit, why are you using the now deprecated exception specifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `first` is a pointer to your element, `*first` will give you a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int& intRefFunction() {
  static int intValue = 42;
  static int* intPointer = &intValue;
  return *intPointer;
}
```

Comment: I just want to illustrate the syntax in as self-contained as possible. However ...

Comment: How about "static int v = 1234; static int* intPointer = &v; return *intPointer;" ? No confusing undefined behaviour ...

Comment: Re "the caller is prone to dereference a null pointer": no, you've already dereferenced it. This code has undefined behaviour whatever the caller does.

Comment: @Mike. No you haven't. That's my point. No dereference happens until someone tries to use the reference.

Comment: @bmargulies: `*intPointer` is a dereference, whatever you do with its value, and gives undefined behaviour if `intPointer` is null. See, for example, the note in C++11 8.3.2/5: "a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior."

Comment: Is that new in C++-11? I have a strong if unreliable memory that it was otherwise once.

Comment: @bmargulies: No, C++03 8.3.2/4 has exactly the same note.

Answer (score 0):

```
ElementType& *first
```

Declares a variable `first` to be, I think, a pointer to a reference to an `ElementType` object. I'm not sure that is even valid C++.

```
&*first
```

If you return this, you are returning the address of the dereferenced object pointed to by pointer `first`, which I believe amounts to just returning `first`.

If `first` is a pointer to the first ElementType item, just return the dereferenced object as `*first`.

By the way, that's not the only thing that looks wrong with your code. I don't think throwing string pointers is good practice (throw an object derived from `std::exception`, such as `std::out_of_range`), nor is including the exception specification (it incurs unnecessary overhead). So you're probably after something more like this:

```
ElementType& front()
{
   if (empty()) {
      throw std::out_of_range("Empty Vector");
   }
   return *first;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ElementType& *first`

Is not legal. You can't have a pointer to a reference.

Just derefence the pointer and you will have a reference to it.

Example, assuming `first` is a pointer:

```
ElementType& r(*first)
return r
```